# Default stringify for objects, equivalent to Java's toString?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have just take a look at the 3º tutorial from dart, creating the rating component. I was wondering if there is same method which is called when stringifying an object, something similar to Java's toString.

For example:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
System.out.println(myObject);
```

Will call MyClass.toString() if overwriten, else will call it's parent until java.lang.Object is reached giving a default toString.

I find kind ugly (completely subjective) doing:

```
<span ng-repeat="star in cmp.stars" > {{star.toString()}} </span>
```

I would rather do:

```
    <span ng-repeat="star in cmp.stars" > {{star}} </span>
```

And give the implementation of how I want it to display at an averwritten method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it works like this for `print`, String interpolation or Angular mustaches.

By overriding the `String toString()` method on your object the displayed value will be the result of this `toString()` call. If there's no `toString()` defined in the class hierarchy the `toString()` of `Object` will be called (which will return `Instance of 'MyClass'` for `class MyClass{}`).

Comment: Could you provide how it would be done. I only got `Instance of 'MyClass'`.

Comment: Ahh, Ok. I thought you meant that the method to overwrite was print... Thx.

Answer (score 30):

If you have something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    String data;

    MyClass(this.data);

    @override
    String toString() {
        return data;
    }
}

MyClass myObject = new MyClass("someData");
print(myObject); // outputs "someData", not 'Instance of MyClass'
```

I think this might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interesting look how Rating component was implemented in Angular Dart UI project. Check [this](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/blob/master/lib/rating/rating.dart) out.

Sergey.

Comment: Wow, cool component. I'm still in the angular tutorial series, but clearly the next one will be angular dart ui.