# inspect() does not print to console

Tags: dart, debugging, intellij-idea, console

I am trying to debug an issue in a pure dart code. In flutter I use `debugPrint()` and I found the note that `inspect()` does this with Dart. However, nothing happens, `log()` neither. Only `print()` provides an input. However, I have a complex object, and I would rather not transform all its content into strings.

So how can I output a data object for debugging purposes with Dart (and IntelliJ Idea)?

Comment: Add an overridden toString method to your class and have it output whatever information you really need for debugging purposes, and print that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921222/default-stringify-for-objects-equivalent-to-javas-tostring

Comment: Thanks, yes this is actually a way to do it. But do you know, what this inspect() command is about (I changed my question, because I wrote console() instead of inspect() )

Comment: From my understanding it is just a way to represent an object in a place you may want to look at its contents when stepping through code with a debugger.