# How can I pass an instance of a object by value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two model class. One class I have defined PreferenceModel as a property. PreferenceModel contains one property called showData which is a bool.

Now my json is printing:

```
 preference: Instance of 'PreferenceModel'
```

I want it to print

```
preference: { showData:true }
```

QUESTION UPDATE.

@Salman Ahmed Is Correct. But my question was what if you want to define PreferenceModel as a property in the another model class. For instance UserModel class. and you want json to be `preference: {showData:true}` not the other one above `preference: Instance of 'PreferenceModel'`

Right now when I `print(UserModel.preference.showData)` I get true. But I want to pass like this   `preference: {showData:true}` on json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default stringify for objects, equivalent to Java's toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921222/default-stringify-for-objects-equivalent-to-javas-tostring)

Answer (score 1):

You have create a method `toJson` in your parent and child classes to convert the class object to map object. For example your class `PreferenceModel` should be defined as below with `toJson()` method.

```
  class UserModel {
  User? user;

  UserModel({this.user});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    user = json['user'] != null ? User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (user != null) {
      data['user'] = user!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class User {
  PreferenceModel? preferenceModel;

  User({this.preferenceModel});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    preferenceModel = json['preferenceModel'] != null
        ? PreferenceModel.fromJson(json['preferenceModel'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (preferenceModel != null) {
      data['preferenceModel'] = preferenceModel!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class PreferenceModel {
  bool? showData;

  PreferenceModel({this.showData});

  PreferenceModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    showData = json['showData'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['showData'] = showData;
    return data;
  }
}

void main() {
  var map = {
    "user": {
      "preferenceModel": {"showData": true}
    }
  };
  UserModel userModel = UserModel.fromJson(map);
  print(userModel.toJson());
}
```

OUTPUT:

{user: {preferenceModel: {showData: true}}}

Comment: That's an awefully verbose way to do that `toJson()`. It can be done much simpler by `Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'showData': showData};`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I used an online JSON-to-Dart model converter for the purpose of generating the Dart model classes in the response. The objective was to provide a timely and accurate response by leveraging automated tools in the development process.

Comment: Whatever tool that was produced some horribly non-idiomatic Dart: use of `new Map`, use of `new` keyword at all, unnecessary `this.`, unnecessary type on `final data`, etc